# What does text storage and permission mean?

Tags: local-storage, file-permissions

I apologize but I'm not familiar with this at all. So I need to create a text storage called `data.txt` and set the permission to `0666`. Can someone explain to me what that means?

Comment: I think you need to read up on unix file permissions. There is a lot of documentation on the web, but here is a place to get started: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm.

Comment: Also, the "text storage" just means a text file (unless there is more context I'm not aware of).